# How to redirect binding paths?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm having a class which has multiple collections and these collections are depending on each other. (Think of a `DataTable`'s `Columns` and `Rows`).
What I would like to achieve is that I can set the `DataContext` of a `DataGrid` to my class and set the binding path of a column to an item of the first collection (`DataTable.Column`). 
But the `DataGrid` should show a list of items of the second collection. (`DataTable.Rows`)

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<object> Collection1 { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> Collection2 { get; set; }

    public void AddBinding()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass()
        {
            Collection1 = new List<object>
            {
                "Item1",
                "Item2",
                "Item3",
                "Item4",
            },
            Collection2 = new List<List<object>>
            {
                new List<object>
                {
                    "Value1 linked to Item1",
                    "Value2 linked to Item2",
                    "Value3 linked to Item3",
                    "Value4 linked to Item4",
                },
                new List<object>
                {
                    "Value5 linked to Item1",
                    "Value6 linked to Item2",
                    "Value7 linked to Item3",
                    "Value8 linked to Item4",
                },
            }
        };

        var grid = new DataGrid();
        grid.DataContext = myClass;

        grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Binding = new Binding("Item1")
        });
        grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Binding = new Binding("Item2")
        });
        grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Binding = new Binding("Item3")
        });
        grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Binding = new Binding("Item4")
        });
    }
}
```

I wonder if it is possible? Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: "how to achieve this?" - convert this data structure to DataTable and use DataTable.DefaultView as ItemsSource?

Comment: This isn't possible because we are having a lot of issues with DataTable in our PCL's and we need a custom implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inheriting DynamicObject in the Row object you can override the methods GetDynamicMemberNames, TryGetIndex, TryGetMember, TrySetIndex, TrySetMember.
These methods makes it possible to use the []-indexers to get or set a specific value (Column).

Set the Rows collection as ItemsSource and set the values in the Columns as Binding from the GridColumn

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<string> Columns { get; set; }
    public List<MyRow> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class MyRow : DynamicObject
{
    public MyClass OwnerClass { get; set; }
    public List<object> Values { get; set; }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return OwnerClass.Columns;
    }

    public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
    {
        if (indexes.Length == 1 && OwnerClass != null)
        {
            if (indexes[0] is string stringIndex && OwnerClass.Columns.Contains(stringIndex))
            {
                result = Values[OwnerClass.Columns.IndexOf(stringIndex)];
                return true;
            }
            else if (indexes[0] is int intIndex)
            {
                result = Values[intIndex];
                return true;
            }
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(binder.Name) && OwnerClass.Columns.Contains(binder.Name)))
        {
            result = Values[OwnerClass.Columns.IndexOf(binder.Name)];
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    public override bool TrySetIndex(SetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, object value)
    {
        if (indexes.Length == 1 && OwnerClass != null)
        {
            if (indexes[0] is string stringIndex && OwnerClass.Columns.Contains(stringIndex))
            {
                Values[OwnerClass.Columns.IndexOf(stringIndex)] = value;
                return true;
            }
            else if (indexes[0] is int intIndex)
            {
                Values[intIndex] = value;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(binder.Name) && OwnerClass.Columns.Contains(binder.Name)))
        {
            Values[OwnerClass.Columns.IndexOf(binder.Name)] = value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```